# NSURLConnection gives "A server with the specified hostname could not be found" error randomly

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, wcf

I'm trying to consume a .NET WCF Webservice from my iOS App using [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request returningRespose:&response error:&error]

Most of the time connection is made and it works fine but sometimes randomly it gives ***"A server with the specified hostname could not be found"*** error.

When it gives this error, for like 10-20 seconds after that it instantly gives the same error but after some time it works again. It shouldn't be a network issue because i've tested it with an Android app with the same network and the connection is made every single time.

I've tried with a asmx webservice and same thing happens.

The same webservice works fine while consumed in an Android app.

**Has anyone experienced this kind of problem? What should i do to fix it?**

**What should i do at code side ?**

Answer (score 0):

Increase timeout interval of your request. Something like this

```
urlRequest.timeoutInterval = NSTimeInterval(10.0)
```